# Trying to create postgres extension periods returns Cannot load library: unknown error 126

Tags: postgresql

I am currently trying to build a historized database using postgres 12.4.0 and the periods extension. Everything is working fine so far on my Win10Pro X64 machine.
I setup another machine with Win10Pro X64 the same as mine - as far as I can tell:

- install postgres
- stop postgres service
- copy contents of periods release zip https://github.com/xocolatl/periods/releases/download/v1.2/periods-v1.2-pgREL_12_STABLE-windows-x64.zip to postgres/12 dir
- start postgres service

now, when I run `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS periods CASCADE;`, I get the following error only on the other machine:
konnte Bibliothek

> »C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/12/lib/periods.dll« nicht laden: unknown error 126
> (in english: could not load library periods.dll)
> Everything works fine on my machine
> The dll file is there
> The required extension btree_gist is there and loadable

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use something like [dependency walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) to figure out what libraries are required by `periods.dll`, but cannot be found. Are binaries 64-bit or all 32-bit or did you mix?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks. I didn't know about that tool.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue using dependency walker. The periods.dll in that release needs VS2015 debug dlls. My computer had them due to me having the sdk installed.
I needed to copy

- vcruntime140d.dll
- ucrtbased.dll

to c:\Windows\System32

Comment: I would report that as a bug to whoever built the executable.